# При создании нового проекта в PyCharm, в виртуальную среду автоматически устанавливается устаревшая версия pip

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, интерпретатор, venv

При создании нового проекта PyCharm с помощью virtualenv, при выборе базового интерпретатора [image: Расположение интерпретатора в системе]
[image: Расположение интерпретатора при создании проекта],
автоматически устанавливается устаревшая версия pip, хотя в базовом интерпретаторе она обновлена до последней версии, о чем свидетельствует ответ консоли.
Версия pip в виртуальном окружении.
[image: терминал виртуального окружения]

Реальная версия pip, установленная в интерпретаторе.
[image: cmd]

Почему так происходит и как пофиксить? Буду рад услышать варианты.
С наилучшими)

Answer (score 3):

Пип устанавливается заново в любой только что созданный venv. Версия pip по умолчанию для venv - связана с версией Python и полностью независима от любой версии pip, установленной в системе.  Более старая версия исходит из wheel file, связанного с модулем stdlib surepip. Это позволяет пользователям создавать venv даже при отсутствии подключения к Интернету.

В стандартной библиотеке venv есть флаг: **--without-pip**, который может здесь помочь. В таком случае будет использоваться системный pip.

Python 3.9+ venv имеет параметр **--upgrade-deps** для немедленного обновления версий pip/setuptools после создания среды.

А вообще, нет ничего страшного что pip в venv немного более старый чем системный.